# NPM throwing missing dependency but it exists?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

I have been having a problem which i have been trying to figure out for an hour or so and i cant seem to figure it out.

When i include google maps in to my app.js file then reload i get an error from npm of the following:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 14 errors                                                                                                                                                                                      
5:05:10 PM
This dependency was not found:

* fs in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs


This relative module was not found:

* ./config/constants in ./node_modules/googlemaps/lib/index.js, ./node_modules/googlemaps/lib/placeSearchText.js and 11 others  Asset     Size
```

but when i run npm install --save fs it runs and completes but i still get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

npm version: 5.3.0

Google Maps: latest

Node Js: 6.11.1

Comment: Isn't `fs` part of Node standard? What version of NPM and Node are you using? According to NPM, `fs` isn't a package anymore: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs

Comment: That is strange. I wonder why google maps requires it as a dependency?

Comment: Edit your question adding more info: NPM's version, Node's version, Google Maps' version...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't add comments yet, but try to uninstall the package like this:
`npm uninstall <package name>`  then re-install it again: `npm install <package name>`.

Sometimes it works.

Comment: too bad, I hope you find the answer. @Dazeh

Comment: 1: `rm -rf node_modules`

2. `npm cache clear`

3. `npm install`

good lucks! sometime works

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the `request` package has been deprecated and `fs` is a dependency of `request` so webpack is no longer compiling it. The github issue is here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

It looks like a temporary fix is to add the following to the webpack config file but I'm not sure where one would find it

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```